# Hibernate detached criteria join with restriction

Tags: hibernate

Suppose I have the ff entity in hibernate:

Payment Entity w/c has the ff. attributes:

```
paymentId
person (also an entity)
type
status
date
```

In HQL, I read the data using this HQL query: `"FROM Payment WHERE person.firstName LIKE'%" + keyword + "%' AND person.lastName LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'`. This works fine, but how can I achieve the same results this time using detachedcriteria?

I'm new in here so please bear with me if my question is a little vague.

Comment: Any help will be so much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? This is basic stuff, that is well explained in the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria

Comment: You could try and post your answer down here and mark it as resolved, so that people know this question has a proper answer.

Comment: Something like this:   DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Payment.class);
  dc.createAlias("person", "p")
  .add(Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.like("p.firstName", "%" + keyword + "%"), 
    Restrictions.like("p.lastName", "%" + keyword + "%"))
  );